# Vuzix m300 Speech and Touchpad in UNIty3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, vuzix

Is there any way to include Speech recognition and Touch pad support for Vuzix m300 using Unity.
The code shared is for Android Studio development. I am requesting for Unity3D.

Comment: where is the code shared?

Comment: Probably not. We had to develop our own for m100. It’s not too hard but cumbersome as you need to bridge every Android public method to a C# version. Simply look into plugin creation in Unity and focus on the bridge part as you already have the jar. For touch pad, try and see if it converts to Unity input. Print all input and see which goes when swiping. It may be mapped to GetAxis already.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me look for the ways to expose the JAR for Unity

Answer (score 0):

To use Vuzix Speech Recognition and touchpad, 
First You need to download and install Vuzix SDK from https://www.vuzix.com/Developer/KnowledgeBase/Detail/43.

Getting Started Code for the Vuzix M300 Speech SDK https://www.vuzix.com/Developer/KnowledgeBase/Detail/52

Comment: Those steps are for Android Studio. I am asking for unity 3D. Thanks btw

Comment: @PradeepKulasekaran, You need to create android plugin using VUZIX SDK and import in unity.
This link will help you to create Android plugin https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/creating-an-android-java-plugin-for-unity3d/